# Pytest fixture not tearing down object between tests, even though scope is set to function

Tags: python, pytest

I am using pytest fixtures to give a custom object to my tests. I want a fresh object for each test since some of the tests modify the object.

```
from gen3release.filesys import io
import pytest
from gen3release.config import env
import json
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import hashlib
import os
import copy

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def env_obj():
    return env.Env("./data/test_environment.$$&")
```

The default scope is function which means that the object should give me a new object each for each test.

I have 5 tests for a module called io.py

When I run this test

```
def test_store_environment_params(env_obj, loaded_env_obj):
io.store_environment_params("./data/test_environment.$$&", env_obj,"manifest.json")
sowers = env_obj.sower_jobs
expected_sower = loaded_env_obj.sower_jobs
assert expected_sower == sowers
env_params = env_obj.ENVIRONMENT_SPECIFIC_PARAMS
expected_params = loaded_env_obj.ENVIRONMENT_SPECIFIC_PARAMS
assert expected_params["manifest.json"] == env_params["manifest.json"], f"Got: {env_params}"
io.store_environment_params("./data/test_environment.$$&/manifests/hatchery/", env_obj,"hatchery.json")
assert expected_params["hatchery.json"] == env_params["hatchery.json"]
```

Before this test

```
def test_merge_json_file_with_stored_environment_params(env_obj, loaded_env_obj):
  os.system("cp ./data/test_manifest.json ./data/manifest.json")
  # h1, j1 = io.read_manifest("./data/manifest.json")

  env_params = env_obj.ENVIRONMENT_SPECIFIC_PARAMS["manifest.json"]
  print(env_params)
  io.merge_json_file_with_stored_environment_params("./data", "manifest.json", env_params, env_obj, loaded_env_obj)
  with open("./data/manifest.json") as f:
    with open("./data/testmerge_manifest.json") as f2:
      assert f2.read() == f.read()
  os.system("rm ./data/manifest.json")
```

This test fails because the env_obj the test receives has been modified.  How do I get pytest to give me a new object every time?

Comment: Can you show a bit more to be able to [reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Side note: it is usually not a good idea to name a module like a standard library module (`io` in this case).

Comment: Edited for clarity

Comment: Thanks - that is a lot of code, but unfortunately nothing we can reproduce, without knowing what `Env` does. Anyway, you can easily make sure that `env_obj` is different in each test (for example by printing it), and the problem has probably to do with the `Env` class - I would guess it uses some global state.

Comment: Oh you know what, I had not considered that with the Env class. There are class variables that are modified. pytest is giving me new instances.